# VirtualBox: The medium can't be used as the requested device type

Tags: assembly, virtual-machine, virtualbox, nasm, bootloader

I'm learning how bootloaders work and how to make my own in assembly. I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/view/hello-world-boot-loader) to make a simple bootloader. I tried the "Never ending loop boot sector" part, compiled it with NASM, by typing `nasm bootloader.asm -f bin -o bootloader.bin` in the cmd: it works. I then converted the bin to a iso file using WinBin2Iso, it looks like it works, but then when I try selecting the iso for a virtual machine, here's what it says:

```
Failure while opening disk image 
C:\...\bootloader.iso.

The medium 'C:\...\bootloader.iso' can't be used as the requested device type.

Error code : E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component : MediumWrap
Interface : IMedium {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda}
Called function : IVirtualBox {0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945}
Returned code : VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

(I have a french version of VB so I translated the french text so some things might not be exact)

What is happening? Is the code in the tutorial outdated? Or am I not doing this the right way?

Thanks.